# How can i convert all factories to one factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i convert below different factories into one factory.I am confuse how to implement get and save method if we have one factory.

Factory.js

```
 angular.module("App").factory('RiskService', function ($resource) {
        'use strict';
        return $resource('app/risk/rest/risk/:id');
    });

    //RiskEventTypeInfo
    angular.module("App").factory('RiskEventTypeInfo', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('app/risk/rest/risk/getRiskEventTypeInfo/:id', {}, {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET'
            },
            'get': {
                method: 'GET'
            }
        });
    });

    //RiskCauseCategoryInfo
    angular.module("App").factory('RiskCauseCategoryInfo', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('app/risk/rest/risk/getRiskCauseCategoryInfo/:id', {}, {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET'
            },
            'get': {
                method: 'GET'
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a factory that returns an object for each function.

```
//RiskFacade
angular.module('App').factory('RiskFacade', ['RiskService', 'RiskEventTypeInfo', 'RiskCauseCategoryInfo', function (RiskService, RiskEventTypeInfo, RiskCauseCategoryInfo) {
        return {
          getRisk: RiskService.get,
          getRiskEventType: RiskEventTypeInfo.get,
          getRiskCauseCategory: RiskCauseCategoryInfo.get
       };
}]);


RiskFacade.getRisk({id: 123}, function () {});
```

The same as before but with the $http service.

```
   angular.module('App').factory('RiskFacade', ['$http', function ($http) {
       return {
         getRisk: function (id) {
           return $http.get('app/risk/rest/risk/' + id);
         },
         getRiskEventType: function (id) {
            return $http.get('app/risk/rest/risk/getRiskEventTypeInfo/' + id);
         },
         getRiskCauseCategory: function (id) {
           return $http.get('app/risk/rest/risk/getRiskCauseCategoryInfo/' + id);
         }
       };
     }]);

    //then

    RiskFacade.getRisk(123).success(successMethod).error(errorMethod);
```

Comment: I wan to get rid of $resource change my implementation to $http with one factory and functions inside..

Comment: I edited my response to use the $http. If you want to add more complicated logic then You should compose the RiskFacade service with a new factory for each endpoint.